# White navbar, placement issues in Bootstrap

Tags: heroku, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

Today I wanted to install Twitter Bootstrap in my Sinatra app on Heroku. Unfortunately, there are some display issues: the navbar is white instead of dark, and the placement of the content isn't right.

I use the Bootstrap version from www.bootstrapcdn.com. My app is here: http://sultry-depths-9340.herokuapp.com/ and this is my layout.haml: http://pastebin.com/zWQ6H5st

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New version of bootstrap (2.1.0) use white navbar, it is default now. You can use `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">` and it become dark background.

Comment: Well, that did it. I should really begin to read changelogs regularly. :D